# efficient use of std::move to aggregate all object instances in a std container

Tags: c++11, containers, std, move-semantics

I need to centrally accumulate certain entity creations in my program into a container and I want to use the efficiency of std::move with a move constructor to aggregate all entities created anwhere in the program into one container witout extra copying or instance allocations. Unfortunately using the most popular std::vector container brings with it vector internal management overhead ( or is that compiler implementation dependent??)

For example

```
class Item {
public :
  static int Count;
  int ID;

  Item() : ID(Count++)
  { cout<<"   Item CREATED - ID:"<<ID<<endl; }

  Item(const Item &itm) : ID(Count++)
  { cout<<"   Item COPY CREATED - (ID:"<<ID<<") <= (ID:"<<itm.ID<<")\n"; }

  Item(const Item &&itm) : ID(Count++)
  { cout<<"   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:"<<ID<<") <= (ID:"<<itm.ID<<")\n"; }

  ~Item() { cout<<" Item DELETED - (ID:"<<ID<<") \n\n"; }
};

int Item::Count = 0;

void VectorOfItemTest() {
  std::vector<Item> ItemVec;

  for(int idx=0; idx<3; idx++) {
    std::cout<<" { loop "<<idx<<std::endl;
    Item itemInst;
    ItemVec.push_back(std::move(itemInst));
    std::cout<<" } "<<idx<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

produces output :

```
-----------------------------
 { loop 0
   Item CREATED - ID:0
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:1) <= (ID:0)
 } 0

   Item DELETED - (ID:0)
 { loop 1
   Item CREATED - ID:2
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:3) <= (ID:2)
   Item COPY CREATED - (ID:4) <= (ID:1)
   Item DELETED - (ID:1)
 } 1

   Item DELETED - (ID:2)
 { loop 2
   Item CREATED - ID:5
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:6) <= (ID:5)
   Item COPY CREATED - (ID:7) <= (ID:4)
   Item COPY CREATED - (ID:8) <= (ID:3)
   Item DELETED - (ID:4)
   Item DELETED - (ID:3)
 } 2

   Item DELETED - (ID:5)
   Item DELETED - (ID:7)
   Item DELETED - (ID:8)
   Item DELETED - (ID:6)
```

---

Is it possible to avoid the extra copy-s that causes matching delete-s inside the for loop?

Is there a container (or can we use std::vector in any way) where we get all loop outputs looking as follows ?

```
 { loop X
   Item CREATED - ID:X
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:X+1) <= (ID:X)
 } X
 Item DELETED - (ID:X)
```

I have looked at
[Why std::move is required to invoke move assign operator of std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532884/why-stdmove-is-required-to-invoke-move-assign-operator-of-stdvector)
[Why does std::move copy contents for a rvalue or const lvalue function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147226/why-does-stdmove-copy-contents-for-a-rvalue-or-const-lvalue-function-argument)
and a few others here but its still not clear how I can use std::vector (or other containers) efficiently using std::move.

I found a rejected question [Hard time understanding object lifetime, copy, move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416262/hard-time-understanding-object-lifetime-copy-move-constructor) asking close to what I am referring to here I guess.

[UPDATE 1] Using pointers : My existing code uses pointers which avoid extra allocation and copy. I am trying to eliminate pointer usage through out my code moving forward - hence this question. I will revert to pointers if this change doubles the memory allocations and copy-s.

[UPDATE 2] @MooingDuck suggestion of using *[std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)* solved this issue without the need for reserve() or noexcept move constructor. I was actually in the process of designing an array of std::vector wrapper to avoid std::vector resizing as I also need pointers to the entities remain valid to support legacy code.  *[std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)* seems to do precisely that

```
"The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted
as needed. Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of
a std::vector because it does not involve copying of the existing
elements to a new memory location. On the other hand, deques 
typically have large minimal memory cost; a deque holding just one 
element has to allocate its full internal array (e.g. 8 times the 
object size on 64-bit libstdc++; 16 times the object size or 4096 
bytes, whichever is larger, on 64-bit libc++)."
```

The deque test

```
void DequeOfItemTest() {
  std::deque<Item> ItemDQ;
  for(int idx=0; idx<3; idx++) {
    std::cout<<" { deque loop "<<idx<<std::endl;
    Item itemInst;
    ItemDQ.push_back(std::move(itemInst));
    Item &refToItem = ItemDQ[ItemDQ.size()-1];
    Item *ptrToItem = &refToItem;
    std::cout<<" } "<<idx<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

This produces the same output now as I wanted - a single entity allocation on the stack followed by a single move into a container and a single delete of the stack allocation

```
-----------------------------
 { deque loop 0
   Item CREATED - ID:0
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:1) <= (ID:0)
 } 0
   Item DELETED - (ID:0)

 { deque loop 1
   Item CREATED - ID:2
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:3) <= (ID:2)
 } 1
   Item DELETED - (ID:2)

 { deque loop 2
   Item CREATED - ID:4
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:5) <= (ID:4)
 } 2
   Item DELETED - (ID:4)

   Item DELETED - (ID:5)

   Item DELETED - (ID:3)

   Item DELETED - (ID:1)

-----------------------------
```

[Note] as suggested in the comments and answer below (and by VS2022) declaring move constructor and move assignment operators as noexcept is good practice as it lets containers like std::vector use the more efficient move operation instead of a copy operation.

Comment: [std::vector::reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: Why not use pointers?  Either std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr ?

Comment: thanks @MooingDuck - I had used resize earlier - I see reserve does not create containee instances yet. @ Michaël Roy - Yes, my current code uses pointers and I am trying to eliminate pointer usage.

Comment: After reading your question and comments again, you *might* be interested in `std::deque`. It's rarely used, but allows you to add or remove items from both ends of a list without *ever* doing the copy of all elements. It's very slightly slower than a vector in almost every other case though

Comment: Hmm... I am actually in the process of designing an array of vectors wrapper to avoid resizing as I also need pointers to the entities remain valid. for now I dont forsee any deletions from the vector/container either - so std::deque does seem a better fit - I assumed it was same as list and did not provide random access - but I see now that it does provide random access like a vector. I will try using it and update here.

Comment: Thanks @MooingDuck . std::deque be a better fit to my requirements as is than std::vector ! I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Sidenote: You should make your move constructor/assignment `noexcept` regardless. It makes a lot of things better

Comment: Also note: if you can avoid having the local in the first place, and use `ItemDQ.emplace_back(...)` to construct your class, then you can also eliminate the moves.

Comment: I used a local instance here for illustration purpose to keep the question minimal - in practice I can have any section of my code create a new entity on the stack that I want to accumulate. I will definitely check how I can avoid that and use emplace_back . Thanks !

Comment: @MooingDuck - As of now I dont use exceptions in my project anywhere - given that should I still use noexcept?

Comment: Yes, even if you don't use exceptions, marking move constructors and assignment as `noexcept` will tell other code that the move operators are safe to use.  In many cases, `std::vector` will use move constructors and assignment if they're `noexcept`, but will use copy constructors and assignment otherwise.

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks - that makes sense and I also understand @ HowardHinnant answer better now.

Comment: `const Item &&` Don't do this. You want your rvalue references to be non-const. It doesn't matter in this case, but in this case move is meaningless anyway.

Comment: @n.m. Can you please expand why move is meaningless? I just tested DequeOfItemTest() commenting out the  move constructor and I get "Item COPY CREATED" instead of "Item MOVE CREATED". I am assuming move is more efficient than copy - is that not so?

Comment: There is nothing magic about the move. It is as efficient or inefficient as you make it. *For this class* the move does exactly the same thing as the copy, so it is exactly as efficient as the copy, so it doesn't make much sense to maintain separate move members.

Comment: @n.m. thanks - based on your response I tried "Item(const Item &&itm) default;". It just made deque use the copy constructor. From what you are saying, it almost seems like the whole purpose of a move constructor is defeated if we are allowed to define a move constructor where we end up implementing it the same as a copy constructor. Have I understood your point correctly?

Comment: `Item(const Item &&itm) default;` This doesn't look like valid code. I have no idea why you think this is my suggestion. My suggestion is to **remove `const`** from the move constructor parameter, here and in all your code, because you never need it. It is OK to have a move constructor that does nothing useful if you are just researching when a move constructor is or is not getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things required to get your stated ideal:

First, you'll have to mark your move constructor as `noexcept`.  And if it then throws an exception, `std::terminate` is called, so it really must be designed so that it never throws.

```
Item(const Item &&itm) noexcept : ID(Count++)
{ cout<<"   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:"<<ID<<") <= (ID:"<<itm.ID<<")\n"; }
```

This gets you down to:

```
{ loop 0
   Item CREATED - ID:0
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:1) <= (ID:0)
 } 0

 Item DELETED - (ID:0) 
 { loop 1
   Item CREATED - ID:2
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:3) <= (ID:2)
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:4) <= (ID:1)
 Item DELETED - (ID:1) 
 } 1

 Item DELETED - (ID:2) 
 { loop 2
   Item CREATED - ID:5
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:6) <= (ID:5)
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:7) <= (ID:3)
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:8) <= (ID:4)
 Item DELETED - (ID:3) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:4) 
 } 2

 Item DELETED - (ID:5) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:6) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:7) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:8)
```

The only thing that has changed above is that your copies from before are turned into moves.

The reason this is needed is so that `vector::push_back` can maintain the strong exception guarantee from C++98/03.  This means that if any exception is thrown during the `push_back`, there are no changes to the value of the `vector`.

Second, you need to `reserve` sufficient space in the vector so that `push_back` never needs to allocate a bigger buffer:

```
std::vector<Item> ItemVec;
ItemVec.reserve(3);
```

This gets you down to the ideal:

```
 { loop 0
   Item CREATED - ID:0
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:1) <= (ID:0)
 } 0

 Item DELETED - (ID:0) 
 { loop 1
   Item CREATED - ID:2
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:3) <= (ID:2)
 } 1

 Item DELETED - (ID:2) 
 { loop 2
   Item CREATED - ID:4
   Item MOVE CREATED - (ID:5) <= (ID:4)
 } 2

 Item DELETED - (ID:4) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:5) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:3) 
 Item DELETED - (ID:1)
```

When `push_back` is called with `ItemVec.size() == ItemVec.capacity()`, a new buffer is allocated, and all of the existing elements are moved to the new buffer ... unless your move constructor is not `noexcept`, in which case all of the existing elements are **copied** to the new buffer.

Comment: Well, there's also the possibility of `emplace_back`, which gets rid of 3 destructors and 3 moves, depending on his real code. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98852352c4b35f2b

Comment: `emplace_back` did not change the logging output for me (once the first two steps were done).

Comment: Right. I was able to use `emplace_back` to eliminate the logging by eliminating the local that we move from, which is why I noted "depending on his real code".

Comment: thanks @HowardHinnant for your quick responses. the noexcept did make the extra copy-s into extra move-s. When the vector size is in the thousands, I guess each vector resize will lead to thousands of extra move-s overhead due to std::vector design. This does eliminate copy-s though assuming move-s are minimal overhead.